# GCP Cloud Build fails with permissions error even though correct role is granted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I setup a Cloud Build Trigger in my GCP project in order to deploy a Cloud Function from a Cloud Source Repository via a .yaml file. Everything seems to have been setup correctly and [permissions granted according to the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#granting_permissions_to_run_builds_and_deployments), but when I test the trigger by running it manually, I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Missing necessary permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for on resource [MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT]. Please grant the roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role. You can do that by running 'gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding [MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT] --member= --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser']

Now first of all, running the suggested command doesn't even work because the suggested syntax is bad (missing a value for "member="). But more importantly, I already added that role to the service account the error message is complaining about. I tried removing it, adding it back, both from the UI and the CLI, and still this error always shows.

Why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of trial and error. The documentation seems to be incorrect (missing some additional necessary permissions). I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52069200/1797628) to get me there.

In short, you also need to add the `cloudfunctions.developer` and `iam.serviceAccountUser` roles to the `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` account, and (I believe) that the aforementioned cloudbuild service account also needs to be added as a member of the service account that has permissions to deploy your Cloud Function (again shown in the linked SO answer).

The documentation really should be reflecting this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. Honestly I think google cloud documentation is quite poor.

Comment: Saved my life! This is definitely not clear on the documentation. Even when I tried to do the command suggested on the error message ```gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding {} --member= --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser ``` it wouldn't work as this wasn't the real recipient of the required permissions

Comment: Thanks, with little documentation was struggling to get a reply from the API, this helped.